# Set value from Firebase Realtime Database to RadioButton

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-radiobutton

Is there a way I can set a `RadioButton` with a string value in my Firebase Realtime Database? Is it possible? Below is my code.

```
DatabaseReference questions_beg_java = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Questions").child("BeginnerJava").child("QuestionOne");
        questions_beg_java.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String question_one = dataSnapshot.child("question_one").getValue().toString();
                String answer_one = dataSnapshot.child("answer_one").getValue().toString();
                String answer_two = dataSnapshot.child("answer_two").getValue().toString();
                String answer_three = dataSnapshot.child("answer_three").getValue().toString();

                //radioButton1.
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

What do I add to set a value to the `RadioButton`? As in retrieving it from Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: How do you want to set the RadioButton? Which value from the database should be used? Could you use a [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)?

Comment: I am having a string value in my database And I want to give the radiobutton the same name as the string value.

Comment: The Android [`RadioButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton) view inherits from [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView), so you can use [`setText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: This is shameful. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll add it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android [`RadioButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton) widget is basically a [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) with some extra styling and functionality. It is therefore inheriting all methods from `TextView`, including [`setText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)).

This means that you can do something like:

```
String answer_one = dataSnapshot.child("answer_one").getValue().toString();
radioButton1.setText(answer_one);
```